# Laravel: update a column after selecting the max id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

i want to select the max id from "Users" table and update a column of that row named "status" which is initially set to "0" and after update it will be "1". how can i do that?i tried something like this

```
$id = DB::table('users')->InsertGetId(
      ['status' => 0]
    );              
        if($status && $id)
        {   
           DB::table('users')
           ->select max("id")
           ->update(['status' => 1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DB::table('users')
   ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
   ->take(1)
   ->update(['status' => 1]);
```

Comment: @incorporeal thanks for the fix, of cource it's `orderBy()`, not `order`. )

Comment: will u please tell me what is the work of 'take(1)' here?  @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: `take(1)` takes just one record from the table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset